# Looking for DimensionFinancialTag relation

Tags: sql-server, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

Is there a relation between DimensionFinancialTag and (DimensionFocusBalance or Ledger or MainAccount or DimensionAttributeValueCombinison)

I have a query in sql server and i want to join DimensionFinancialTag  to DimensionFocusBalance or Ledger or MainAccount or DimensionAttributeValueCombinison)

Can anybody help in this regard

Regards

Answer (score 3):

I would try to accomplish this task over the relation from `DimensionFinancialTag` to the `DimensionAttributeValue` and from there to the Ledger Dimensions down to the `DimensionAttributeValueCombination`.

Have a look at the following image:
[image]
Source: MSDN - [Ledger account combinations - Part 1 (Dimensions)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ax_gfm_framework_team_blog/2013/02/15/ledger-account-combinations-part-1-dimensions/)